# Trying to exec INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect' gives error

Tags: database, xampp, mariadb

hello i'm trying to work with mariaDb using JSON, so i found out that i need to `INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect'` in other to practice mysql with json using php, so whenever i run this `INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect'` it gives me this error - `#1126 - Can't open shared library 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\ha_connect.dll' (errno: 0, The specified module could not be found.)` then i noticed that `\lib\plugin\ha_connect.dll` dir isn't on my xampp

And whenever i try to create this functions it gives me the same error

```
create function jsonvalue returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_array returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_array_add_values returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_array_add returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_array_delete returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_nonull returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_key returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_add returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_delete returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_list returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsonvalue returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create aggregate function json_array_grp returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create aggregate function json_object_grp returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_array_add_values returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_add returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_delete returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_object_list returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsonlocate returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_locate_all returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsoncontains returns integer soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsoncontains_path returns integer soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_item_merge returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_get_item returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsonget_string returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsonget_int returns integer soname 'ha_connect';
create function jsonget_real returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_set_item returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_insert_item returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_update_item returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_file returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jfile_make returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function json_serialize returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_array returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_array_add_values returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_array_add returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_array_delete returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object_nonull returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object_key returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object_add returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object_delete returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_object_list returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_item_merge returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_get_item returns string soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_set_item returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_insert_item returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_update_item returns real soname 'ha_connect';
create function jbin_file returns string soname 'ha_connect';
```

i have tried checking it on the web, but i haven't found any solutions to it, at least not any for windows, all responses were for ubuntu users. My MariaDB version is 10.1.19 in case it will be helpful

Comment: What is the question? Is this "why XAMPP does not package ha_connect.dll"? Is this "where do I get ha_connect.dll"?

Comment: why can't i run the command INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect' using xampp? and why isn't the dir to ha_connect.dll 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\ha_connect.dll' not found when after installing xampp?

Comment: Because xampp does not package it. They package what they think is important, they do not even have a lib subdirectory,and plugin_dir actually points to a non-existing directory.

Comment: so how can i get it?

Comment: From a standard mariadb download https://downloads.mariadb.org/ . you can unpack zip file. and put into your xampp.